# How to upload 2 files using curl --upload-file

Tags: curl

When I try this

```
curl -u username:password --upload-file file1.txt http://example.com/folder/
```

It works. I am able to upload file.

But it doesn't work for 2 files. How can I upload multiple files using curl?

If I understood correctly, -F is for posting a file as if there is an endpoint that accepts @Post requests and File in a body or multi-part body, etc.

My situation is different. I don't have an endpoint. It is simple transfer of one file from one location to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lookup `curl --manual`, you will get a nice example to upload multiple files:

```
curl -u username:password --upload-file "{file1,file2}" http://www.example.com
```